# Span Wrapping a Span

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following:

```
<span id="span_1" style="overflow: auto;">
<span id="span_2" style="font-size: 200px; background-color: red;">Testing</span>
</span>
```

When I try to get the height of the wrapping span `span_1` using jQuery - it gives me 19px. Even though the inner span `span_2` has a font-size of 200px and its computed height on firebug is 225px.

Why is the wrapping span not fully wrapping around the inner span?

I am basically trying to find the **exact** remaining height of a particular element. This element can have many children but I want to know how much height it has left. So the idea is to wrap everything within that element in a span and calculate height using jQuery but so far I don't understand why the above doesn't work.

Better ideas? I can't wrap a div around the contents as it will be effected by line-height.

Comment: Do inline elements actually have a computable height?

Comment: Yes, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmEv9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block;` to the parent span.

Comment: This has the same issue as wrapping the span in a div. There is extra spacing at the top and bottom. I think t will also be effected by line-height.

Comment: I don't know how are you using line-heigh, but you can expect that any other solution will be affected by line-height too. Why don't you put the background in the parent span? or add `display: inline-block;` to the child span too?

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("#span1").outerHeight();`

Comment: This wont work, it'll return just the same as firebug's computed height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

> display: block;
>   position:relative;

to your inner and outher span too. Span is an inline element, it doesn't have width or height by default.